# Trend of or trend for in the academic graph

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, academic-writing

I want to write an introduction about this graph:
[image: line chart]

Are these sentences correct and have a good structure ?

“The graph gives information about the percentage of recycling trends of four different types of materials (paper and cardboard, glass containers, aluminum cans and plastics) over 28 years between 1982 and 2010.”

I am a little bit confused about the use of “trends”

1. Should I use Plural or singular?
2. About preposition: trends of or trend for ?
3. Is trend a suitable word here?
4. It seems that I repeated preposition “of” a lot. How I can change the sentense without repeated “of”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Trends" is plural*.
2. "Of" is the correct preposition to use in this instance [See definition 6b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of)
3. Yes, trends is a suitable word here if you mean "the general direction of change".

*A general rule (with many exceptions) is that nouns that end in "s" are often plural. A better rule is that nouns that both end in "s" and whose the second-to-last letter is not "s" or a vowel are often plural.

There are still exceptions, such as "pants" is often used as a singular noun, derived from the phrase "a pair of pants", due to "pants" being used as a shortened form of "pantaloons", which were (originally, as that term has been used to describe various garments over the centuries) a sleeve-like garment that covered a single leg and were worn in pairs.

Short answer: English is weird.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I mean, in this situation, does we need to use plural form or singular?

Comment: @Question You are describing more than 1 trend, so the plural form should be used. If you were describing a single trend (e.g. "Percentage of Recycling Aluminum"), then the singular form should be used.